# Understanding the R package "gsynth

Tags: panel-data, causality, difference-in-difference, synthetic-controls

I am currently working with the R package "gsynth" based on the publication "Generalized Synthetic Control Method: Causal Inference with Interactive Fixed Effects Models" by Xu (2017).

See also: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsynth/gsynth.pdf

According to this, X represents time-varying covariates. I am not sure if I understand this correctly. Do I just need to use any known variables that vary over time? What do I have to pay attention to?

[image: Code]